# Python list methods comprehesion

Tags: python, list

The program takes a number x - the length of the list. Create a list and populate it from the console. After that, the number y will be entered, which may or may not exist in the list. Your task is to print how many times the number y occurs in the list.

Example:

```
input:
5 # is the number x
0 # start of list
5
15
1
2 # end of list
5 # is the number y
output: 1
```

My attempt:
But output is 0
Can you help me please?

```
x = int(input("x = "))
a = []
for _ in range(x):
    numbers = int(input("number = "))

y = int(input("y = "))
counter = 0
for i in a:
    if y in a:
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Comment: You need to add each numbers to your (yet unused) list `a` with `a.append(int(input("number = ")))` instead of saving it to a temporary and useless `numbers` variable

Comment: Also, your `if` should be: `if y == i:`

Comment: with this Создать список, состоящее из кубы чисел от 0 до x, где x будет введено с консоли (сделать input() для x). Использовать list comprehension.
Пример:
input: 5
output: [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25]

input: 3
output: [0, 1, 4, 9]

Comment: x = int(input("x = "))
a = []
for _ in range(x):
    numbers = int(input("number = "))
for numbers in range(0, numbers+1):
    a.append(numbers ** 3) 
    numbers += 1
print(a)

Comment: my attempt, bot output is incorrect,

Comment: and it's without list comprehesion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
x = int(input("x = "))
a = []
for _ in range(x):
    number = int(input("number = "))
    a.append(number)  # add this line

y = int(input("y = "))
counter = 0
for i in a:
    if i == y:  # change condition here
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Comment: with this Создать список, состоящее из кубы чисел от 0 до x, где x будет введено с консоли (сделать input() для x). Использовать list comprehension. Пример: input: 5 output: [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25] input: 3 output: [0, 1, 4, 9]

Comment: `[x**2 for x in  range(int(input("x: ")) + 1)]`

Comment: thanks, but where i need to put this piece of code

Comment: x = int(input("x = "))
a = []
for _ in range(x):
    numbers = int(input("number = "))
for numbers in range(0, numbers+1):
    a.append(numbers ** 3) 
    numbers += 1
print(a)   where I need to change it?

Comment: do you get it? @Sandeep Rawat

Comment: No I didn't get it, I think you need to follow some python tutorials